# Tic-tac-toe game for Windows console

Tags: c++, game, console, tic-tac-toe, windows

I am doing C++ for over a year and this is my game I tried making tic-tac-toe. And it's also my first program that uses multiple source files.

**main.cpp**

```
#include"Header.h"
#include"GUI.h"
#include"UI.h"

int main()
{
    int* board = new int[9] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
     // 1 2 3
     // 4 5 6
     // 7 8 9
    int place{ 0 };  //   /\
                     //   ||  -1
    bool turn{ false }; // true = O, false = X
    bool win{ false }; // flase = no win, true = win
    int count{ 0 }; // counts ammount of moves

    

    while (!win && count < 9)
    {
        place = question(board) - 1;
        system("cls");
        turn = change_board(board, turn, place);
        switch (check_win(board))
        {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            print(board);
            change_color(3, 0);
            cout << "\nPlayer Two won\n";
            win = !win;
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            print(board);
            change_color(4, 0);
            cout << "\nPlayer one won\n";
            win = !win;
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if (!win)
    {
        system("cls");
        print(board);
        change_color(2, 0);
        cout << "\nIt's a draw\n";
    }
    change_color(7, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Header.h**

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>
```

**GUI.h**

```
void change_color(int text, int background);
void print(int* board);
int question(int* board);
```

**GUI.cpp**

```
#include"Header.h"
char symbols[3]{ ' ', 'X', 'O' };



void change_color(int text, int background)
{
    HANDLE  hConsole;
    int color{ text + 16 * background };

    //0 = Black 8 = Gray
    //1 = Blue 9 = Light Blue
    //2 = Green a = Light Green
    //3 = Aqua b = Light Aqua
    //4 = Red c = Light Red
    //5 = Purple d = Light Purple
    //6 = Yellow e = Light Yellow
    //7 = White f = Bright White

    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, color);
}

void color_print(char symbol)
{
    switch (symbol)
    {
    case 'X':
        change_color(4, 0);
        cout << symbol;
        change_color(7, 0);
        break;
    case 'O':
        change_color(3, 0);
        cout << symbol;
        change_color(7, 0);
        break;
    default:
        cout << ' ';
        break;
    }
    return;
}
void color_print(int symbol, int place)
{
    switch (symbol)
    {
    case 1:
        change_color(4, 0);
        cout << 'X';
        change_color(7, 0);
        break;
    case 2:
        change_color(3, 0);
        cout << 'O';
        change_color(7, 0);
        break;
    default:
        change_color(2, 0);
        cout << place + 1;
        change_color(7, 0);
        break;
    }
    return;
}
void print(int* board)
{
    for (int column{ 0 }; column < 2; column++)
    {

        for (int row{ 0 };row<2;row++)
        {
            cout << "  "; color_print(symbols[board[3 * column + row]]); cout << "  |";
        }
        cout << "  "; color_print(symbols[board[3 * column + 2]]); cout << endl;
        cout << "-----------------\n";
    }
    for (int row{ 0 }; row < 2; row++)
    {
        cout << "  "; color_print(symbols[board[row + 6]]); cout << "  |";
    }
    cout << "  "; color_print(symbols[board[8]]); cout << endl;
    return;
}
void print_to_ask(int* board)
{
    for (int column{ 0 }; column < 2; column++)
    {
        for (int row{ 0 }; row < 2; row++)
        {
            cout << "  "; color_print(board[3 * column + row], 3 * column + row); cout << "  |";
        }
        cout << "  "; color_print(board[3 * column + 2], 3 * column + 2); cout << endl;
        cout << "-----------------\n";
    }
    for (int row{ 0 }; row < 2; row++)
    {
        cout << "  "; color_print(board[row + 6], row + 6); cout << "  |";
    }
    cout << "  "; color_print(board[8], 8); cout << endl;
    return;
    
}
int question(int* board)
{
    int place{ 0 };
    print_to_ask(board);
    cout << "\n\n   Please, input the place where you want to do your turn: "; cin >> place;
    if (place < 1 || place > 9 || board[place - 1] != 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        change_color(0, 4);
        cout << "Invalid option\nPlease retry\n\n";
        change_color(7, 0);
        place = question(board);
    }
    return place;
}
```

**UI.h**

```
bool change_board(int* board, bool turn, int place);
int check_win(int* board );
```

**UI.cpp**

```
#include"Header.h"
bool change_board(int* board, bool turn, int place)
{
    board[place] = int(turn) + 1;
    return !turn;
}
bool check_win_side(int* board, int side)
{
    for (int x{ 0 }; x < 3; x++)
    {
        if (board[x] == board[x + 3] && board[x] == board[x + 6] && board[x] == side)
            return true;
    }
    for (int x{ 0 }; x < 3; x++)
{
    if (board[x * 3] == board[x * 3 + 1] && board[x * 3] == board[x * 3 + 2] && board[x * 3] == side)
        return true;
}
    if ((board[0] == board[4] && board[0] == board[8] && board[0] && board[0] == side) || (board[2] == board[4] && board[2] == board[6] && board[2] == side))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int check_win(int*board)
{
    if (check_win_side(board, 1))
    {
        return 2;
    } else if (check_win_side(board, 2))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 5 → 4. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `check_win` function make sure to check if `board[0]` is not equal to zero before comparing it to side. If `board[0]` is not equal to zero, it means that this cell is not empty, and you need to check if it belongs to the side player before comparing it.

Consider the scenario:

`board[0]` contains 1, indicating that player one (`X`) has placed their symbol in the top-left cell.

Now you want to check if player one (`X`) has won. In this case, side would be `1` (representing player one).

If you didn't check `board[0]` before comparing it to side, the condition `board[0] == side` would evaluate to `true` because `1` (player one's symbol) is indeed equal to `1` (the side being checked). However, this would be incorrect because `board[0]` already contains a move by player one, and it doesn't necessarily mean they have won yet.

Aside from this, the code looks acceptable for test or interview material.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback, @TheLeb, I have fixed it now and it works.

Comment: You're welcome. Good work on this. Please click the check ✔️ next to my answer to make it the accepted answer?